# TypeError: AuthenticateService.checkUser is not a function

Tags: angularjs

**TypeError: AuthenticateService.checkUser is not a function**

```
I am submitting a login page with credentials, for sending the credentials to the server I have service **AuthenticateService** with $http.post, calling the method in the above mentioned service from the contactLoginCtrl.js (controller),
during that I am encountering this error
```

below is the code for **AuthenticateService**

```
  angular.module('app.services')
.service('AuthenticateService',['$http',function($http){

    return{         

        checkUser : function(uname, pword){

             var indata = { "password": pword, "username":uname };
             var req ={
                          method: 'POST',
                          url: 'http://localhost:8083/spring2/login',
                          data: indata
                      }

                  $http(req).then(function (response) {
                      console.log(response);
                      return response;
                  }, function (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                      return error;

                  });
                }

            }

}]);
```

below is the controller code contactLoginCtlrls.js

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('contactLoginCtrl',['$rootScope','$scope','AuthenticateService','$location',function($scope,AuthenticateService,$location){

    $scope.authenticate =  function(userModel){
        var userName = userModel.username;
        var password = userModel.password;
        console.log(userName+password);

         ***AuthenticateService.checkUser(userName,password);***
    };

}])
 The above highlighted line is causing the error could some one please check this?


----------------------ignore the below section------------------------
```

content added only for skipping the error from stackoverflow  to add some more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to inject four services into your controller `'$rootScope', '$scope', 'AuthenticateService', '$location'` but you've only declared three of them in the function params.

Instead try:

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
       .controller('contactLoginCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'AuthenticateService', '$location', 
        function($rootScope, $scope, AuthenticateService, $location)
        {...}
```

Comment: @sajeetharan, Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

You controller does not have `$rootScope` injected as a parameter. Change it like this,

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('contactLoginCtrl',['$rootScope','$scope','AuthenticateService','$location',function($rootScope,$scope,AuthenticateService,$location){
```